# Azure Devops Authorization Issue when having access to multiple directories

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Azure DevOps authorization to fetch projects for a particular signed user using this (**[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0)**) endpoint. When the signed-in user has access to a single directory in the devOps( which can be found using https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-IN this) there is no problem in getting the access token and then fetching the projects using that token.But the problem comes when a user has access to multiple directories then I am seeing an unusual behavior that when the page loads and lets say the user is not signed-in in azure devOps then it asks for sign in and then sign in page keeps on loading again and again no matter how many times I log in. Here is what my profile looks like, I have access to only 1 directory.

[image]

I have registered an application on azure devops for the OAuth 2.0 Workflow as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops)
In that registered application I have provided application URL, Redirect URI & the Scopes required.
Can someone tell what could be the possible reason for the recursive login that is appearing again and again.

Comment: It works well when I have two directories, I think maybe your issue could have something to do with how you register the application. Could you share some details about how you register it?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT So I registered using this link (https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register) and then I just Simplly fill up the required mandatory details App Name , App URL & Redirect URI and then I specified the scopes and then I registered the application and then I was using the App Id and App Secret in the OAuth Flow.

Comment: I haven't registered one application using link above, but it always works well on my side for user with access to several directories. Just to clarify, do this issue come after you set the OAuth2.0 workflow? Have you tried to do similar actions using `Edge+Private Window` or `Chrome+incognito window`, issue persists?